# How to use reselect to optimise state re-renders

Tags: reactjs, reselect

At the moment I'm getting a lot of re-renders because of this state updating even though the value is the same. I've read up on reselect but I can't get it to work quite as I expect and wondering what I'm doing wrong.

I've got a hook that checks for the state and returns true or false depending on if the email exists. The email property is either null or a string.

```
const test2 = useMemo(() => test(), []);
const userProfile = useSelector(test2);
const NO_USER_PROFILE = useMemo(() => !userProfile.email, [userProfile]);
const HAS_ACCESS_TOKEN = useMemo(() => !!authentication.access_token === true, [authentication]);
```

And then in my selector file I have the below:

```
export const selectProfile = ({ profile }) => profile.me.email;
export const test = () => createSelector(
  [selectProfile], 
  email => {
    if (email) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
);
```

At the moment I'm getting many falses consoled outt and when it is true I get a few of these too. I was expecting createSelector to only update if there is a change but this doesn't seem to be the case. Would love for someone to point out where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: There is no reason to use useMemo in any of the examples. You can use useMemo when you need to pass a parameter to a selector like [createSelectPerson](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors/blob/master/src/selectors.js#L7-L10) where the component can [pass an id to it](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors/blob/master/src/components/Person/index.js#L25-L28) so a selector is created only when the id changes. Full examples [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors). No reason to use useMemo when it returns a primitive value as well.

Comment: I found it reduced the rerenders.